# Creating a partial file name with a variable in C++

Tags: c++, variables, filenames, bgi

I'm making a C++ program/game that uses the "graphics.h" header and I'm trying to create a map with tiles. There are 66 tiles and each file name is different. I want to display them all without having to write nearly identical lines over and over.

This is what I have so far (pseudocode):

```
filename = a + number + b;
readimagefile (filename, left, top, right, bottom);
```

Where a is "bg(", followed by a number from 1 to 66, and then b, which is ").bmp". I want the filename to be like this: "bg(number).bmp". However, what I have above is clearly the incorrect syntax.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::stringstream str;
str << a << number  <<  b << ".bmp";
```

Then `str.str()` returns a c++ std::string and `str.str().c_str()` returns a 'c' type string

Comment: @ubernickeh - you can of course include "xxx" anywhere in the stream to add other formatting and set number formats see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654991/good-tutorial-for-stringstream-manipulation-in-c

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, a number may be converted to its string representation using `to_string` (or `to_wstring`).  For example,

```
a + std::to_string(number) + b
```

(The Visual C++ 2012 Standard Library implementation includes `to_string` and `to_wstring`.)

This is far more straightforward (less code, easier to read) than creating a `std::stringstream` to do the formatting (it's also less capable and more restricted, but for simple use cases like the one you describe, it is sufficient).

Alternatively, [Boost.LexicalCast](http://www.boost.org/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) may be used to convert an object to a string; internally it uses a `std::stringstream`, but it may be optimized for numeric types and other types for which using a stream would be overkill.  Using `boost::lexical_cast`:

```
a + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(number) + b
```

Comment: @sixlettervariables:  As of yesterday, it is named [Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<66; i++)
{
   stringstream stream;
   stream << "bg(" << i << ").bmp";
   string fileName = stream.str();
}
```